# Why mysql query returns a different result?

Tags: mysql, sql

combine two tables using the below `select` query:

```
SELECT item_name,batch_no,invoice_no,invoice_date,damaged_qty,qty,unit_vat,unit_discount,unit_price,packing,free FROM
(SELECT item_name,batch_no,invoice_no,invoice_date,damaged_qty,qty,unit_vat,unit_discount,unit_price,packing,free
FROM damage_stocks AS S UNION ALL
SELECT item_name,batch_no,invoice_no,invoice_date,qty,qty,unit_vat,free,unit_discount,unit_price,packing
FROM purchase_invoice AS D)  AS alias_table
GROUP BY  invoice_no,item_name,batch_no
HAVING COUNT(*)=1 and invoice_no=1
ORDER BY item_name,batch_no,qty;
```

Resultant output :

```
'MM TONE_', '1', '1', '2015-06-24', 10, 10, 0.00, 2.00, 0.00, 20.00, '10'
```

You see, it displays `free` as 10 but in my `damage_stocks` table, free column contains no value and in the `purchase_invoice` table, the column `free` contains `2` for the `invoice_no` 1.

```
select free from purchase_invoice where invoice_no = 1;
```

output:

```
2
```

this

```
select free from damage_stocks where invoice_no = 1;
```

returns an empty value, because there are no values are added.

And my question is,

- Why `free` column displays 10 instead of 2, since the free column in `purchase_invoice` contains `2` for the `invoice_no` 1 ?
- How I get the output as `free` col's output as 2 instead of 10?

Comment: `and invoice_no=9` how this correlates with `column free contains 2 for the invoice_no 1.`?

Comment: sorry, forget to edit the question. Now, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 'free' column's sequence mismatch in purchase_invoice query.
Query should be:

```
SELECT item_name,batch_no,invoice_no,invoice_date,qty,qty,unit_vat,unit_discount,unit_price,packing,free FROM purchase_invoice AS D
```

I placed 'free' column at the end of select sequence.

Comment: is that the order important?